# jQuery Ajax loading image not loading on ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the below jQuery snippet for an ajax loading image which I use on numerous sites, for some reason it wont disply the loading image when an ajax request is fired.

jQuery:

```
$(".loading").hide().ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Example Ajax call (working as expected and returning correct data):

```
$('#list').change(function() {
    var vCID = 1;

    if ($.trim(vCID) && vCID != 0)
    {
        var vData = {aid:1001,id:vCID};

        $.ajax(
        {
            url : "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : vData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                $('#itemList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="loading">&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS:

```
.loading {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    background: url('images/loading.gif') no-repeat;
}
```

The HTML code is being affected by the jQuery as `display: none` is being added on page load, there are no errors and if I change `display: block` on the HTML via firebug the loading.gif image shows up.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the DOC: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/ ??? **As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make it with `beforeSend` and `complete` methods:

```
     $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: vData,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(".loading").show();  // <----show before sending
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#itemList').html(data);
        },
        complete: function () {
            $(".loading").hide(); // on complete of ajax hide it.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try changing it to

```
$(".loading").hide();

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(".loading").show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(".loading").hide();
});
```

Instead of chaining it to `$('.loading')` which may not fire an `ajaxStart()` event.